# The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed because of caching

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching, entity-framework-4

i am using caching in entity framework. in a for loop i am hitting the linq query 5 times. first time cache is null so i am storing it in the cache with following cache policy

```
else if (cachedData == null)
        {
            cachedData = this._db.ListsofItems
                .Include(a => aItems)
                .ToList();

            // Save to cache
            cache.Set(cacheName, cachedData, new CacheItemPolicy()
            {
                UpdateCallback = new CacheEntryUpdateCallback(CacheUpdateOnExpiration),
                AbsoluteExpiration = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(50))
            });
```

but second time when i hit the query (this time cache data is not null) it returns query data. in the follwing method when i tries to find the count then it calls dispose method automatically. dont know why.

```
 using (var queries = new Queries(this.Context))
                    {
                        m.Started = queries.Get().Filter(itemstatus: new List<int> { 1.2}, stDate: c.AddMonths(-1), eDate: current, limit: 2000).Count();
                    }
```

so the question is , in second time of execution why count is calling dispose method automatically?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C# **using** keyword calls Dispose() when it is done. Check out this page.

http://www.dotnetperls.com/using

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx

Microsoft quote: "The using statement calls the Dispose method on the object in the correct way, and (when you use it as shown earlier) it also causes the object itself to go out of scope as soon as Dispose is called."

Comment: count is called inside the using block itself